# Strange error message while doing Grails integration testing in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy, integration-testing, applicationcontext

For my project I use: Grails 2.4.4 and IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2

I have a User domain class. I created an integration test for this class. Here it is:

```
package com.kunega

import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class UserIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def setup() {
        def appAdmin = new User(username: 'appAdmin', enabled: true, password: 'password').save(flush: true)
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "findUser"() {
        expect: User.findByUsername("appAdmin") != null
    }
}
```

When I run the 'grail test-app -integration' command I get the following error in the 'Run' tab of IntelliJ:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find ApplicationContext, configure Grails correctly first
at grails.util.Holders.getApplicationContext(Holders.java:97)
at grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.$spock_initializeSharedFields(IntegrationSpec.groovy:41)

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/grails-2.4.4/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
```

[image: Error message]

However, in the 'Console' tab there is this message, which shows that the test passed:

```
|Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
|Completed 1 integration test, 0 failed in 0m 0s
.
|Tests PASSED - view reports in D:\Facultate\Sport app\Kunega\target\test-reports
```

[image]

I don't know what to think about this. Should I consider that the test passed or there is a problem that I need to fix? Let me know if you need more details like BuildConfig.groovy etc. If someone could provide an explanation it would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are performing an integration test for a domain you will need to mock values in it. My recommendation is to use spock with Mock mixin. You may want to also explore the TestFor mixin. As this is an integration test you may also need to mock something like UserRole and Role classes or whatever their equivalent is that you are using. Your code should look something like this:

```
package com.kunega

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin}          for usage instructions
 */
 @TestFor(User)

 //The User class is mocked below but you will also want to mock the integrated classes as this is an integration test
 @Mock([User])
 class UserIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

void setup() {
    mockDomain(User, [
        [username: 'appAdmin', enabled: true, password: 'password']])
}

void "test user exists"() {
    //test logic to test that the user is created in domain
}
}
```

Comment: It has the same effect. I get the following exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find ApplicationContext, configure Grails correctly first
 at grails.util.Holders.getApplicationContext(Holders.java:97)
 at grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.$spock_initializeSharedFields(IntegrationSpec.groovy:41)"